# How to create a pointer to an array and provide methods to access it?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

1. I have to create 2 class member variables:

   a. a pointer to an array of chars.

   b. length of the string
2. Create the member functions to set and get all of the fields.
3. Provide constructors and destructors.
4. Create the functions which:

   a. return the symbol from inputting position;

   b. convert string into char.
5. Overload operation of (+, +=, -, -=) for substrings.

Here is my code so far:

String.h

```
class String
{
private:
    char m_symbol_array{};
    int m_string_length{};
public:
    String()
    {
        m_symbol_array;
        m_string_length;
    }
    //String(char symbol_array, int string_length);
    //void setString(char symbol_array, int string_length);
    void setSymbol_array();

    int getSymbol_array(char symbol_array) { return m_symbol_array; }
    int getString_length(int string_length) { return m_string_length; }

    void string_to_char();
    int return_symbol();

    //String operator+();
    //String operator-();
};
```

String.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<string>
//#include<cstring>
#include"String.h"

//String constructor

//String::String(char symbol_array='d', int string_length = 0)
//{
//  setString(  symbol_array, string_length);
//}
    //String member function
//void String::setString(char symbol_array, int string_length)
//{
//  m_symbol_array = symbol_array;
//  m_string_length = string_length;
//}

void String::setSymbol_array(char symbol_array)
{
    m_symbol_array = symbol_array;
}

void String::string_to_char()
{
    char* char_arr;
    cout << "Please, input the string ";
    string str_obj{};
    std::cin >> str_obj;
    //string str_obj("GeeksForGeeks");
    char_arr = &str_obj[0];
    cout << char_arr;

    //return 0;
}

//int String::return_symbol(){}

//String String::operator+(){}

//String String::operator-(){}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include"String.h"

using namespace std;

//void string_to_char();

int main()
{
    /*String s(1,5);
    s.string_to_char();*/

    String first;
    char sd[5];

    first.getSymbol_array( *sd);
    //first.operator+();
    //String second{ 4,5 };
    //second.operator-();

    return 0;
}
```

The problems occurred when I was trying to make the member variable `m_symbol_array` a pointer to an array, and then provide setters and getters for it.

Comment: What are these statements m_symbol_array;
        m_string_length; in the constructor doing?

Comment: _The problems occurred ..._ What problems?  Please be more specific.

Comment: If your task is to implement `setSymbol_array` equivalent to `std::string::operator=` the expected implementation may be ok, but if by "set the field" you're expected to replace the array in used by the object this will result in a badly designed class: you don't know how the array was allocated, so you cannot free it in the destructor safely; for all you know it could point to some data on the stack or a string literal. Be that as it may the parameter type should be changed to `const char*`; if you use `char` you get the copy of a single character that is gone after the function exits.

Comment: I suspect that `char m_symbol_array` shouldn't be a single `char`.  It should probably represent some sort of array instead.  And similarly, `int getSymbol_array(char symbol_array)` shouldn't return an `int`. But it isn't clear what "the problems" are that you're asking about.  You never mentioned a problem.

Comment: *"The problems occurred"* -- in addition to being more specific, this should be at the beginning of your question, not the end. If you try to hold readers in suspense until the end of your question, readers are likely to move on without reading. (See also [ask], in particular the part about introducing the problem before you post any code, where "problem" means the subject of your question, not your assignment.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a few things. From your include file:

```
private:
    char m_symbol_array{};
    int m_string_length{};
```

Two things. First, you need a pointer to a character array. As you don't know the length at compile time, it should be a char *, not a char, like this:

```
 char * m_symbol_array;
```

Next, let's improve the initialization quite specifically:

```
private:
    char * m_symbol_array{nullptr};
    int m_string_length{0};
```

That is -- make sure that your character pointer is properly initialized to `nullptr`, which is the C++ variable that says, "Not pointed anywhere yet", and the length is 0.

Now, let's look at this:

```
String()
{
    m_symbol_array;
    m_string_length;
}
```

Those two lines in your constructor don't make sense. Remove them.

After this, it gets tricky. This is almost certainly not what you want, so I'm changing the signature:

```
void String::setSymbol_array(const char * symbol_array)
{
}
```

In C++, a series of characters can be represented in one of three ways:

```
std::string theBestWay;
char * theSecondBestWay;
char theWorstWay[10];
```

theBestWay is a class that implements a string. It's part of the standard. In a way, your homework is an attempt to write a version of std::string.

But you're doing that using the second way -- a pointer to a series of characters. And you'll store the length so when you're working on it, you can fiddle with it.

The next thing to know is that when using methods two or three, you should have a character at the very end equal to 0. NOT "0", but zero itself. This is how C and C++ know it has reached the end of the string.

So, I'm not going to write the code, but I'll explain it a little better:

```
void String::setSymbol_array(const char * symbol_array)
{
     // if symbol_array == nullptr, then you should free
     // The allocated memory and set your m_ variable to nullptr;

     // Otherwise get the length of symbol_array (see strlen())
     // Then you can see if you already have enough space (plus one
     // for the 0-byte). If necessary, free the old memory and
     // allocate enough space, then use strcpy() to copy
     // the string.
}
```

I'm not going to write it for you. I'm nudging you in the right direction. See how much further you get.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your `String` implementation.  It needs it be completely re-written.

Try something more like the following instead, taking into account syntax corrections, handling of the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), etc.

String.h

```cpp
class String
{
private:
    char *m_symbol_array = nullptr;
    int m_string_length = 0;

public:
    String() = default;
    String(const char *symbol_array);
    String(const char *symbol_array, int string_length);
    String(const String &src);
    String(String &&src);
    ~String();

    String& operator=(String rhs);

    void setString(const char *symbol_array, int string_length);
    
    char* getSymbol_array() { return m_symbol_array; }
    const char* getSymbol_array() const { return m_symbol_array; }

    int getString_length() const { return m_string_length; }

    String& operator+=(const String &rhs);
    friend String operator+(const String &lhs, const String &rhs);
};
```

String.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
    
int str_length(const char *str)
{
    int length = 0;
    if (str) {
        while (str[length] != '\0') ++length;
    }
    return length;
}

//String constructors
    
String::String(const char *symbol_array)
    : String(symbol_array, str_length(symbol_array))
{
}

String::String(const char *symbol_array, int string_length)
    : String()
{
    setString(symbol_array, string_length);
}

String::String(const String &src)
    : String(src.m_symbol_array, src.m_string_length)
{
}

String::String(String &&src)
    : m_symbol_array(src.m_symbol_array), m_string_length(src.m_string_length)
{
    src.m_symbol_array = nullptr;
    src.m_string_length = 0;
}

//String destructor

String::~String()
{
    delete[] m_symbol_array;
}

//String member functions

String& String:operator=(String rhs)
{
    /*
    std::swap(m_symbol_array, rhs.m_symbol_array);
    std::swap(m_string_length, rhs.m_string_length);
    */

    char *old_symbol_array = m_symbol_array;
    int old_string_length = m_string_length;

    m_symbol_array = rhs.m_symbol_array;
    m_string_length = rhs.m_string_length;

    rhs.m_symbol_array = old_symbol_array;
    rhs.m_string_length = old_string_length;

    return *this;
}

void String::setString(const char *symbol_array, int string_length)
{
    char *new_symbol_array = new char[string_length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < string_length; ++i) {
        new_symbol_array[i] = symbol_array[i];
    }
    new_symbol_array[string_length] = '\0';

    delete[] m_symbol_array;
    m_symbol_array = new_symbol_array;
    m_string_length = string_length;
}

String& String::operator+=(const String &rhs)
{
    int new_string_length = m_string_length + rhs.m_string_length;
    char *new_symbol_array = new char[new_string_length + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < m_string_length; ++i) {
        new_symbol_array[i] = m_symbol_array[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.m_string_length; ++i) {
        new_symbol_array[m_string_length + i] = rhs.m_symbol_array[i];
    }

    delete[] m_symbol_array;
    m_symbol_array = new_symbol_array;
    m_string_length = new_string_length;

    return *this;
}

String operator+(const String &lhs, const String &rhs)
{
    /*
    String ret(lhs);
    ret += rhs;
    return ret;
    */

    int new_string_length = lhs.m_string_length + rhs.m_string_length;
    char *new_symbol_array = new char[new_string_length + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < lhs.m_string_length; ++i) {
        new_symbol_array[i] = lhs.m_symbol_array[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.m_string_length; ++i) {
        new_symbol_array[lhs.m_string_length + i] = rhs.m_symbol_array[i];
    }

    String ret;
    ret.m_symbol_array = new_symbol_array;
    ret.m_string_length = new_string_length;

    return ret;
}
```

I'll leave the rest for you to figure out.

Now, that being said, your `main()` code makes no sense given the `String` class you have shown.  You are trying to construct `String` objects using integers, not strings.  Are you expected to hold an array of integers instead?  Or somehow convert integers into text characters?  I think you need to re-read your requirements.  Either your `String` is expected to do something other than what you have presented here, or your `main()` is just completely wrong.